# Backtracking calculus example with scoop and python

Tags: python, distributed-computing, backtracking

im playing a little bit with scoop and i want to know if i can distribute simple problems like a backtracking in a finite state machine to get all states.

For example:

But i want to print all solutions.

```
solutions = []

def backtraking(state)
 for new_state in state.get_new_states():
  if new_state.is_terminal():
   solutions.append(new_state)
  else:
   futures.submit(backtraking,new_state)

def main():
 task = futures.submit(backtracking,state)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Now in solutions i will have all the solutions for the backtracking  computing, but in a distributed system.

This code is not working, does anyone have some experience with Python and Scoop to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Scoope group

The statement "futures.map(backtraking(new_state))" will call backtraking() with new_state as it's argument, and then call futures.map with the result of the previous call as argument.
I doubt that is what you want to do.

The simplest way to parallelize your program using SCOOP would be by replacing your recursive call to a futures.submit() to backtracking.

Something along the lines of:

```
def backtraking(state)
    for new_state in state.get_new_states():
        if new_state.is_terminal():
            print "A solution"
            valid_list.append(new_state)
        else:
            futures.submit(backtraking, new_state)
```

This will create a Future (basically a task that can be executed concurrently) for every node. Your tree traversal is then performed in parallel, provided you have multiple cores assigned to the program.

If you are seeking maximum performance, you can improve it by only performing a submit on the firsts depth levels, such as (untested!):
def backtraking(state, depth=0)

```
for new_state in state.get_new_states():
    if new_state.is_terminal():
        print "A solution"
        valid_list.append(new_state)
    else:
                    if depth < 3:
            futures.submit(backtraking, new_state, depth + 1)
        else: 
                backtraking(new_state, depth + 1)
```

Hope it clarified things up.